# Verilog naming convention of \add_34/U1_1_6

Tags: syntax, verilog, naming-conventions

Can somebody explain what this naming convention means in the Verilog line below?
I don't know what this `\add_34/....` part means?

```
ADDHXL \add_34/U1_1_6  (.A(n1022),.B(\add_34/carry[6] ),.CO(\add_34/carry[7] ),.S(N11));
```

If I have a wire named `\add_34/carry[6]` in my definition, should I have `\add_34/carry[1]` up to `\add_34/carry[5]`, or is it optional?

I asked this question since compiling a part of my code, I get this syntax error:

> Syntax error at or near token 'wire'.

Here is the code snippet:

```
RandomDelay  R00001(clk,rst_n,2'b10,a34_carry_pri_delayed_7,\add_34/carry[7]);
wire N11_pri_delayed;
```

And here is module defintion:

```
module RandomDelay ( clk, reset_not, seed, input_signal, delayed_signal );
  input [1:0] seed;
  input clk, reset_not, input_signal;
  output delayed_signal;
....
```

Answer (score 5):

It is called an 'escaped identifier'.

When an identifier starts with a backslash, **every character except white space** is assumed to be part of the name. (Thus the standard identifier rules go out the window.)

Thus the identifier in your case is "\add_34/U1_1_6". Identifiers of that type are normally generate by a program.
Thus this is a valid identifier: `\wow!/neverseen[]thissort@;of#++mess`

Let's have a look at the identifier: `\add_34/carry[6]`. Note that the "[6]" is NOT an index! Is is seen as ASCII and part of the name.
The same again for `\add_34/carry[7]`.
It also means somewhere there is a definition which goes:

```
wire \add_34/carry[6] ;
wire \add_34/carry[7] ;
// Note the space    ^ before the semicolon!
```

The other \add_34/carry[... variables  may exist or not as we are all looking at individual wires here.

It is perfectly legal for there to be no \add_34/carry[5] or \add_34/carry[0]

Coming back to your code:

```
RandomDelay  R00001(clk,rst_n,2'b10,a34_carry_pri_delayed_7,\add_34/carry[7]);
```

You must thus place a space before the closing bracket:

```
RandomDelay  R00001(clk,rst_n,2'b10,a34_carry_pri_delayed_7,\add_34/carry[7] );
//                                                             ---->>> Here ^
```

Comment: Also should note that if the variable was declares `wire [7:6] add_34_carry;`, then `add_34_carry[5]` would not exist either, though it would be valid to read and write to it; reads yielding the default value `1'bx`, writes doing nothing.